# When I declare a global variable "Driver" as None, it says Cannot find reference 'find_elements' in 'None' , also, no suggestions are coming

Tags: python, selenium

The code works fine when I run it in Pycharm and in Command line, but this Cannot find reference 'find_elements' in 'None' issue is not getting resolved. There are no suggestions when using driver variable. How can I fix this?
The picture of the issue can be found here https://gyazo.com/a4cae984bfbc1e7aff0e43d380f2354b

````
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = None

@pytest.fixture()
def startingTest():
    global driver
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/")
    yield
    driver.close()

def test_Radion(startingTest):
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, "radioButton")
    buttons[2].click()
    assert buttons[2].is_selected()
    dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID, "dropdown-class-example")
    dropdownDD = Select(dropdown)
    time.sleep(2)
    listD = dropdownDD.options
    print(len(listD))
    dropdownDD.select_by_visible_text("Option2")
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "autocomplete").send_keys("Ru")
    names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-menu-item")
    print(len(names))
    for name in names:
        print("I found this country", name.text)
        if name.text == "Peru":
            name.click()
            break

    assert driver.find_element(By.ID, "autocomplete").get_attribute('value') == "Peru"```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRkhc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2VDQ.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your code, your are using driver before creating it

```py
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # Here it is still None
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe") # here you create it
```

that I think you would have to resolve. Apart from that, as it is a fixture, I would not declare driver as a global but just yield it from the fixture, i.e.

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def driver(): #renamed
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # Not sure about that
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/")
    yield driver
    driver.close()

def test_Radion(driver):
    ...
```

Comment: Adding to the answer, you need to remove `driver = None` declaration at the top.

Comment: @pmadhu
I removed the global declaration, now it works fine. Thank you!
But there is one more little thing, the driver is not recognized as a variable in my test
When I actually type `driver.` suggestions are coming up as expected, but the driver itself is not recognized as a variable in the test.

A screenshot can be found here. Is it how that's supposed to be now? 
https://gyazo.com/2d6d2fd3080989ab413bf125f71a9ad8

Comment: you still have to define it if you don't want to go with the proposed fixture approach. So you can still keep driver = None

Comment: @SimonHawe in this scenario the driver variable is not treated as a webdriver.

Here is a screenshot https://gyazo.com/d1f0da118eabc6c0f231dcef629aa565
It's letting me choose between methods I've already used in the test but no others

Removing `Driver = None` at the top helped to get the suggestions back 

Calling the fixture Driver did not change anything

Comment: But it should work I guess. However, your IDE does not recognize it which is a different story.  You can help your ide by type annotating driver like from typing import Optional driver : Optional[webdriver.Chrome] = None

Comment: You can get the same with the fixture, just type annotate your test like def test_Radion(driver: webdriver.Chrome) and your IDE should be happy

Comment: @SimonHawe I am new here and not sure if saying thank you is required but it really helped me! Thank you a lot!

Comment: No worries. If answers helped you, you can also accept answers and rate answers, just for your information.